# How do I do this? Adding values to the dictionary through user input?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that uses a dictionary to create a personal phone book that keeps track of phone numbers, letting you access them by typing in the contact's name. The key for this dictionary is the name of the person whose phone number you want to retrieve. The value is the phone number. (Key and value are strings)

I want to prompt the user to choose from the following menu options:

1. Add new contact
2. Query a contact
3. Exit

Options 1 and 2 should be implemented in a function -- meaning if the user chooses 1, the program execution should go to a function that performs the addition operation.

Option 1 should allow the user to enter as many contacts as they wish. Then it ends the loop on an empty string value for the key. The function should print the phone book after the names are added.

Option 2 prompts the user for a name and displays the corresponding value. The function should re-prompt the user if key is not found.

I am most definitely stuck, here is my code so far:

```
pb = {"Isaiah":"6504213951", "Will":"7632991650", "Jack":"4319091874",
      "Tim":"2657554886", "Eric":"7837947361", "Joe":"7985579489",
      "Alex":"4616231562", "Steve":"8309117856"}

w = input("would you like to add a contact?")


#h = input("would you like to look up a contact?")
#name = input("state the name")

if w == "yes":
    add(w)

if w == "no":

    query(h)


def add(w):
    for key in pb:
        key = input("enter the key: ")
        value = input("enter the value: ")
    pb[key] = value  

    print(pb)
```

There has to be a more efficient way of doing this. I'm trying to use `if` statements to call the function which has the dictionary addition code in it; but I don't know how to get the user prompts to access that code.

Comment: `for key in pb:` and then you immediately replace the `key` with user input.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to prompt the user to choose from the following menu options

So, make the prompt actually do this - show the menu, and then look for `1`, `2` or `3` in input, rather than `yes` or `no`.

> Option 1 should allow the user to enter as many contacts as they wish. Then it ends the loop on an empty string value for the key. The function should print the phone book after the names are added.

Therefore, `for key in pb:` doesn't make sense here - that will loop for exactly as many times as there are existing entries in the phone book, instead of looking out for the empty string value.

(Passing the input `w` to your `add` function also doesn't make sense - the function ignores it, and indeed it has nothing to do with performing the task.)

> I'm trying to use `if` statements to call the function which has the dictionary addition code in it; but I don't know how to get the user prompts to access that code.

I don't understand the question. your code calls `add` when a specific input is provided; `add` is the function that does what you want in this case (at least, once fixed up to loop properly). So isn't this already solved?

Comment: this is just me trying to figure it out, problem is the instructions I was given aren't very clear, so i don't even know how to start this.